# Mule smtp not sending a message

Tags: file, mule, transfer

I am using **Mule 3.4** and I try to send a file from a folder in the mail.

The console displays:

`connector.file.mule.default.receiver.01] org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver: Lock obtained on file: C:\Users\bekbol\Documents\smtp\test.txt`

My config file is below:

```
<flow name="outcomingSmtp" doc:name="outcomingSmtp">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="${file.outcomingSmtp}" responseTimeout="100000" doc:name="File" pollingFrequency="10000" moveToDirectory="${file.outcomingBackupSmtp}">
    <file:filename-wildcard-filter
        pattern="*.txt" />
    <file:file-to-string-transformer doc:name="File to String"/>
    </file:inbound-endpoint>
    <object-to-byte-array-transformer doc:name="Object to Byte Array"/>
    <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="${smtp.host}" port="${smtp.port}" user="${email.username}" password="${email.password}" to="${header.to}" from="${header.from}" subject="${header.subject}" responseTimeout="100000" mimeType="text/plain" doc:name="SMTP">
    <email:string-to-email-transformer doc:name="String to Email"/>
    </smtp:outbound-endpoint>
</flow>
```

Comment: hello, add your question properly here.!!

Comment: smtp.host=smtp.mail.ru
smtp.port=465

pop3.host=pop.mail.ru
pop3.port=995

imap.host=imap.mail.ru
imap.port=143

email.username=shiko_18%40mail.ru
email.password=shiko3759086

file.outcomingSmtp=/Users/bekbol/Documents/smtp
file.outcomingBackupSmtp=/Users/bekbol/Documents/pop3
file.incomingPop3=/Users/bekbol/Documents/pop3
file.incomingImap=/Users/bekbol/Documents/imap

header.to=bekbol_shynar@mail.ru
header.from=shiko_18@mail.ru
header.subject=Test email subject

Comment: What error does it display in the log?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need

`<file:file-to-string-transformer doc:name="File to String"/>`

nested inside your `<file:inbound-endpoint>`. Move it outside right after you close `</file:inbound-endpoint>` and

remove `<object-to-byte-array-transformer doc:name="Object to Byte Array"/>`

Comment: connector.file.mule.default.receiver.01] org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver: Lock obtained on file: C:\Users\bekbol\Documents\smtp\test.txt